# Write Junit test cases for rest web service by calling it by path

Tags: java, junit, jersey, mockito

I have a jersey web service. I want to write test cases for it.
My service is

```
@Path(value = "/mock")
@Component
public class MockService
{
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MockService.class);


    @POST
    @Path(value = "/{mockrequest:ABCD}")
    @Produces(MediaType.JSON)
    public Response mockOKResponse(@Context ContainerRequestContext request, @PathParam("mockrequest") EnumMockService mockService)
    {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/{mockrequest}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response mockProducesPDF(@Context ContainerRequestContext request, @PathParam("mockrequest") EnumMockService mockService)
    {
        MockAccountTable testccount = jdbcTestAcountDao.getTestAccountResponseBlob(mockService.toString());
        byte[] responseBlob = testccount != null ? testccount.getResponseBlob() : null;
        return Response.ok(responseBlob).build();

    }

}
```

I am planing to write test case for this.Which calls specific method based on the specific reuest.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMockService
    extends TestCaseSrs
{    

    private MockService mockService = new MockService();

    @Override
    @Before
    public void prepare()
        throws Exception
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetIncreasedHardwares()
    {
    //dynamically call method based on request

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to set request type here to call method accordingly rather than calling method directly.

It would be great if some one can help me with the approach.

Comment: Why would you mock MockService? That's the unit under test - if you mock it, your not testing any of your code.

Comment: @SteveD. I think its mistake. I am removing it. Thanks